# OpenVPN TAP network

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn, tap

I have a question about the OpenVPN in TAP configuration.

I want to access local resources through VPN connection from outside network. I think I need TAP configuration, because I want to send broadcast messages (like wake-up certain devices).

I would like to ask about the security issues about the TAP connection, since it is working in bridged mode.
When I connect using openVPN TAP connection from work network to home network, does both networks getting bridged? Or this is still separate virtual interface (tap0), which just get's IP from my home network IP range, however without any real bridging with work network (like somebody else can also access the home network). So the only PC that is accessing my home network is the one I'm using?

Thanks, best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you do not bridge the TAP adapter on the client host with any other interface, then the vpn network will only be accessible from that host you are running the vpn client on.

An exception would be if the client is configured as a router and has routes defined to the vpn subnet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Just to be sure - if the client uses eth0 to access the internet (work network), and client TAP adapter also uses eth0 to access VPN (home network) - the adapters aren't bridged (my home network isn't available to work network) - I think this is the most common use case? The interfaces would be bridged only if I manually make a bridge between TAP and eth0 adapters, but this has to be manually done first, is that right? Thanks, best regards